# Microsoft Visual Studio cannot start your diagnostics session

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing

Today when I tried to run diagnostics I got this error:

[image]

It used to work when I ran it a couple of days ago, I have no idea what has changed.

I found it mentioned here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/254669/microsoft-visual-studio-cannot-start-your-diagnost.html

Any idea what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. The program had actually failed to compile but I had not noticed that. Once I fixed the compile error diagnostics ran fine.